# Prove that $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)=\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove $(A\times C)\setminus (B\times D)=(A\times (C\setminus D))\cup((A\setminus B)\times C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127979/prove-a-times-c-setminus-b-times-d-a-times-c-setminus-d-cupa-setminus)

This is exercise $4.1.9$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Prove that for any sets $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)=\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$, then $(x,y)\in A\times B$ which means $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, and $(x,y)\notin C\times D$. We consider two cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]$ and so $x\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $(x,y)\notin\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]$ and since $x\in A$, then $y\notin B\setminus D$. We consider two cases.

Case $2.1.$ Suppose $y\notin B$ which is a contradiction.

Case $2.2.$ Suppose $y\in D$. From $(x,y)\notin C\times D$ and $y\in D$, $x\notin C$. Thus $x\in A\setminus C$ and so $(x,y)\in\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.

From case $2.1$ or case $2.2$ we obtain $(x,y)\in\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$ and so $x\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$. Since cases $1$ and $2$ are exhaustive, $x\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$. Therefore if $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$ then $(x,y)\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$. Since $(x,y)$ is arbitrary, $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)\subseteq\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$ and also let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $C$. We consider two cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]$, then $x\in A$ and $y\in B\setminus D$ which means $y\in B$ and $y\notin D$. Thus $(x,y)\in A\times B$. Also from $x\in C$ and $y\notin D$, $(x,y)\notin C\times D$ and ergo $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$ and so $x\notin C$ which is a contradiction.

From a contradiction or $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$, we obtain $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$. Therefore if $(x,y)\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$ then $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$. Since $(x,y)$ is arbitrary, $\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]\subseteq(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$.

Ergo $(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)=\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

**One other question:** In the answer to the above linked-post, it is mentioned that for the right-to-left direction of the proof, cases are symmetrical and so we are justified to use the phrase "without loss of generality". In my proof cases turned out not to be symmetrical. Is there another way of proving the right-to-left direction that makes the cases symmetrical$?$

Thanks for your attention.

**Edit:**

$(\leftarrow)$ Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$. We consider two cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]$ and so $x\in A$ and $y\in B\setminus D$. Since $y\notin D$, then $(x,y)\notin C\times D$ and ergo $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus (C\times D)$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $(x,y)\in\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]$ and so $x\in A\setminus C$ and $y\in B$. Since $x\notin C$, then $(x,y)\notin C\times D$ and ergo $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus (C\times D)$.

Since the above cases are exhaustive, $(x,y)\in(A\times B)\setminus (C\times D)$. Since $(x,y)$ is arbitrary, $\bigr[A\times(B\setminus D)\bigr]\cup\bigr[(A\setminus C)\times B\bigr]\subseteq(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ($\Rightarrow$) direction of your proof:  It would have been quicker, after saying that $(x,y) \notin C \times D$, to say that therefore either $x \notin C$ or $y \notin D$.  Your cases could then be:  case (1),  $x \notin C$;  case (2),  $y \notin D$.  (To see why $(x,y) \notin C \times D$ means that $x \notin C$ or $y \notin D$:  write it as $\neg(x \in C \wedge y \in D)$ and then use DeMorgan's law.)

For the ($\Leftarrow$) direction:  After you say "Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary element of $[A \times (B \setminus D)] \cup [(A \setminus C) \times B]$," you cannot say "and also let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $C$."  You have already said what $x$ is -it is the first coordinate of your arbitrary element of $[A \times (B \setminus D)] \cup [(A \setminus C) \times B]$.  You can't change it.  However, there is no need to assume $x \in C$.  For example, in case (1), once you have $y \notin D$, you can say "therefore $(x,y) \notin C \times D$"; you don't need to know $x \in C$ to draw this conclusion.

Comment: Could you please check the edit and say if is it correct now$?$

Comment: Yes, the edit is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

1. $(U\times V)\cap (P\times R)=(U\cap P)\times (V\cap R)$  for any $U,P\subset X$ and $V,R\subset Y$.
2. $(X\times D)^c=X\times(Y\setminus D)$ and $(C\times Y)^c=(X\setminus C)\times Y$.
3. $(C\times D)^c=(C\times Y)^c \cup (X\times D)^c= \big((X\setminus C)\times Y\big)\cup\big(X\times(Y\setminus D)\big)$.

(1) and (2) follow directly by definition of Cartesian product. One can also use "$(x,y)\in...$ type o arguments.

(3) follows by de Morgan's laws and application of (2).

Putting things together

$$
\begin{align}
(A\times B)\setminus(C\times D)&=(A\times B)\cap\Big( \big((X\setminus C)\times Y\big)\cup\big(X\times(Y\setminus D)\big)\Big)\\
&=\big((A\setminus C)\times D\big)\cup \big(A\times (B\setminus D)\big)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a great alternative proof which I was not aware of it. But could you also please answer my questions at the end of the post?

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: Your argument seems fine to me. It is an idiosyncrasy of mine to avoid $x\in...$ arguments once some basic properties of set operations are in place. As for the symmetry of arguments, they avoid unnecessary repetition by just changing the roles of objects in a problem that satisfy similar properties. One has to be cautious however and make sure such symmetry is there. If it's not well, we continue with other logical arguments. In any case, I prefer short clear proofs of simple results and reserve my energy for long proofs of results that are deep or complicated by nature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am at the very beginning of the road and so I am not yet very used to such proofs.

Comment: @KhashayarBaghizadeh: In the beginning $x\in...$ type proofs are of course needed. Once you have mastered some of the basic results those arguments help you prove; use the basic results to simplify things. It is not just the matter of simplification, but that along the way you really understand what the basic results mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your proof of the converse (left to right implication) is a bit confusing but the right to left implication is perfectly fine. What happens when $x\notin C$?

Let's just start with the meaning of $(x,y)\in(A×B)∖(C×D)$. This means that $(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ and $(x,y)\notin (C\times D)$. Then this two conditions are verified simultaneously:

1. $(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ $\iff$ $x\in A$ $\land$ $y\in B$
2. $(x,y)\notin (C\times D)$ $\iff$ $x\notin C$ $\lor$ $y\notin D$

To prove the converse  you can just use the definition of $(x,y)\in[A×(B∖D)]∪[(A∖C)×B]$, i.e., $(x,y)\in A×(B∖D)$ or $(x,y)\in (A∖C)×B$. Suppose that $x\in A×(B∖D)$ then it means that $(x\in A)$ and $(y\in B$ $\land$ $y\notin D)$ then $(x,y)\in (A×B)∖(C×D)$. Because both 1. and 2. are true.The other case is analogous.

To prove the right to left implication you pick $(x,y)\in(A×B)∖(C×D)$. Now you have to divide it in cases which are indeed symmetrical. The cases are the following $x\notin C$ $\lor$ $y\notin D$. If the $x\notin C$ then this holds $(x,y)\in (A∖C)×B$. The other case is analogous.

Comment: $x\notin C$ contradicts the assumption that $x\in C$. Why is that confusing?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for the clarification of the symmetrical nature of the right-to-left proof.

Comment: because you assume two contrary ideas. you start by assuming $x\in C$ and then you assume $x\notin C$ when you assume $(x,y)\in (A∖C)×B$. Note that  can exist elements of $ [A×(B∖D)]∪[(A∖C)×B]$ such that $x\in C$.

Comment: But it is not wrong, is it?

Comment: It is because you can not suppose that $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$ are simultaneously true. This is a paradox.